# Hippie Code Completion in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

In NetBeans, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> that activate the *hippie completion*.

In Eclipse, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

What is it in IDEA?

**Edit:**
*Hippie Completion* is the kind of completion that doesn't require much information about the context. It scans all the word in file(s) and immediately choose the first match.
It originate in some variation of Emacs.

Read more here: http://beust.com/weblog/2005/03/11/hippie-completion-in-eclipse/

Comment: Not on the Mac. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063989/817658

Comment: So why is it called “Hippie Completion”?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found it: `Alt+/` or `Alt+Shift+/`. IDEA call it Expand word.

Comment: (a) You omitted a macOS shortcut.  (b) And no, IntellliJ does indeed call it *Hippie completion*, at least nowadays. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion).

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> stopped working on recent Macbooks.

You can change the shortcut, for example to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, in your perferences. The feature is called `Cyclic Expand Word` in IntelliJ 14.

Comment: See my answer for where this shows up in Eclipse on Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063989/817658

Answer (score 0):

Yet another home for hippie completion - Eclipse on Mac: it's called "Word Completion" and is typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

## Hippie completion in IntelliJ

See [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion).  To quote:

> *Hippie completion* is a completion engine that analyses your text in the visible scope and generates suggestions from the current context. It helps you complete any word from any of the currently opened files.

When using that documentation page, notice that the page is set to show keyboard shortcuts for one particular platform. To switch platforms, use the *Shortcuts* pop-up menu in the bar at upper-right corner of the window.

## macOS

- Press `⌥ /` or choose `Code | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word` to search for matching words before the caret.
- Press `⌥ ⇧ /` or choose Cod`e | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)` to search for matching words after the caret and in other open files.

## Windows OS

- Press `Alt+/` or choose `Code | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word` to search for matching words before the caret.
- Press `Alt+Shift+/` or choose `Code | Code Completion | Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)` to search for matching words after the caret and in other open files.